# Routes with parameters in angular4

Tags: angular

all

I develop a new auxiliary site. Users will be referenced to this site from main site using reference like: http://auxiliary-site?ownerId=some-guid

I made AppRoutingModule:

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { ConfigurationsComponent } from './configurations/configurations.component';
    import { CreateConfigurationComponent } from './create-configuration/create-configuration.component';
    import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './pageNotFound/pageNotFound.component';


    const routes: Routes = [
        { path: ':ownerId', redirectTo: 'new-configuration/:ownerId', pathMatch: 'full' },
       { path: 'configurations/:ownerId', component: ConfigurationsComponent },    
       { path: 'new-configuration/:ownerId', component: CreateConfigurationComponent },
       { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
   ];

   @NgModule({
       imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
       exports: [RouterModule]
   })
   export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

I referenced this module to AppModule:

```
    @NgModule({
        imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpModule, AppRoutingModule, PaginationModule.forRoot(), ModalModule.forRoot()],
        declarations: [AppComponent, ConfigurationsComponent, CreateConfigurationComponent, PageNotFoundComponent],
        bootstrap: [AppComponent],
        providers: [ConfigurationsService, CreateConfigurationService, ImageMapper]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

but than I launch my app and go to http://localhost:3000?ownerId=some-guid or http://localhost:3000/new-configuration?ownerId=some-guid I catch: 404 Page not found.

That can I do to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Call the url as 'http://localhost:3000/new-configuration/some-guid'. If you want to use as querystring parameter in your URL you can remove ':ownerId' part from route config.

https://angular.io/guide/router#configuration

Answer (score 0):

As per defined routes, way of URL writing will be like this

```
 http://localhost:3000/some-guid
 http://localhost:3000/new-configuration/some-guid
```

In that case no need to add query parameter.